# Creating a loop on a [1..10] array in Jade

Tags: arrays, numbers, iteration, pug

Wasn't there a way to write down an array as 1..10 ?

I'm trying to write an each loop, but it seems not to be working, I have to write each value manually. I was pretty sure we could do this :

```
- each val in [1..10] // or 1..100 or whatever
    li(class="list#{val}")
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical loops can be written like this in Jade:

```
- for (var val = 0; val < 10; val++)
    li(class="list#{val}")
```

Comment: Yes, but wasn't there the 1..10 way ? Or am I mixing this with another language ?
Anyway, thank you, I totally forgot about the "for" way :)

Comment: As far as I can tell from http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/, there is no `1..10` syntax in Jade.

Comment: You're welcome! If my solution solved your problem do tick the checkmark to the left near the score to indicate that.